# jQuery Validate unobtrusive - Enable validation for hidden fields

Tags: jquery-validate, unobtrusive

i am use asp.net mvc 5, about jquery validate unobtrusive, jquery validate is 1.13 version. I have searched very much answer,  Although this problem have solve，But I want to know another method.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });   //valid

$("#form1").data("validator").settings.ignore = []; //invalid,all input validate invalid

$("#form1").data("validator").settings.debug = true;//valid,if use this method,debug ture model is open, why?
```

if put code in $(document).ready. all code is useless

how Enable validation for hidden fields only for one form?

Comment: Instead try `$("#form1").validate().settings.ignore = []`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enabling the validation for all hidden fields , its better to enable validation for only the ones you want.

you can do this by assigning a class to the hidden fields you want to validate and then  using the following code.

```
// Add special-hidden class to the hidden fields you want to validate.
var validator = $("#formID").validate({ rules: rules });
// this line basicially tells the validator to ignore hidden fields apart from the ones with class special-hidden
 validator.settings.ignore = ':hidden:not([class~=special-hidden])';
```

If you want to enable validation for all hidden fields , use

```
 validator.settings.ignore = '';
```